# javascript - How do i use .click on an <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I cant figure out why this won't work. My friend said to try use `.click` or `.select` to test for a click on the option but nether of them worked.

**My html**:

```
<body>
<form>General
    <hr>Full Name:
    <br>
    <input Type="text" name="name">
    <br>Gender:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" Name="gender" value="Male">Male
    <input Type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
    <br>Birthday:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="bday" placeholder="mm/dd/yy">
    <br>Email Adress:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>PayPal address:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="PayPal" placeholder="for when we start paying staff">
    <br>Short Biography:
    <br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>Apply:
    <hr>Username:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Your Ingame Name">
    <br>What Rank Are You Applying For:
    <br>
    <select>
        <option id="Dev" value="Developer">Developer</option>
        <option id="Headadmin" value="HeadAdmin">Head Admin</option>
        <option id="Headmod" value="HeadMod">Head Modetator</option>
        <option id="Headbuilder" value="HeadBuilder">Head Builder</option>
        <option id="admin" value="Admin">Admin</option>
        <option id="mod" value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
        <option id="builder" value="Builder">Builder</option>
    </select>
    <br>Why do WE want you (Rank you picked above):
    <br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>How Many Hours Can You Be On a day:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="day">
    <br>how many days can you be on a week:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="week">
    <br>have you been staff before?
    <br>
    <select>
        <option value="yes">yes
            <option value="no">no</select>
    <br>Test:
    <hr>
    <div id="DevTest">Devtest</div>
    <div id="admintest">admin test</div>
    <div id="modtest">mod test</div>
    <div id="HAtest">head admin test</div>
    <div id="HMtest">head mod test</div>
    <div id="HBtest">headbuilder test</div>
    <div id="buildertest">buildertest</div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <textarea readonly rows="5" cols="30">Staff Contract: ---------------- 1. As a staff member, YOU, are represent the "Piggalot Gaming Network" both online and offline. this means; A. If WE, The "Piggalot Gaming Network" Community,</textarea>
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox" value="test" required>by clicking this you agree to the staff contract
    <br>
    <input type="reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Application">
</form>
```

**My JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Dev").Click(function(){
        $("#DevTest").show();
        $("#HAtest").hide();
        $("#HMtest").hide();
        $("#HBtest").hide();
        $("#admintest").hide();
        $("#modtest").hide();
        $("#buildertest").hide();
     }); 
    $("#Headadmin").Click(function(){
        $("#HAtest").show();
        $("#DevTest").hide();
        $("#HMtest").hide();
        $("#HBtest").hide();
        $("#admintest").hide();
        $("#modtest").hide();
        $("#buildertest").hide();
     });
 });
```

Here the link to a Fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/a2nw2sus/1/

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? Did you include jQuery? `Click` should be `click` as JavaScript is case-sensitive. Also, you usually bind on the select element, not the options.

Comment: @j08691 Thank you! its working now :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) does not work that way. Listen for a [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) in [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) instead:

```
$('#id_for_your_select').change(function () {
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
    switch (selected_value) {
        case 'Developer': {
            // do something
            break;
        }
        case 'HeadAdmin': {
            // do something else
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

In http://jsfiddle.net/a2nw2sus/2/ I fixed the spelling error (`click()` vs `Click()`), and lo: it does not work in Chrome. In Firefox it works, but you must not take this for granted!

Comment: I Found the problem it was i had a capital 'C' in click. Thanks to @j08691 for pointing it out!

Comment: Please see my added comment. It does not work at least in Chrome.

Comment: can you post a JSfiddle of my html with your answer added to it? :) ps thanks for the help

Comment: Nope, otherwise I had to charge you my usual fees for being lazy. ;) Only copy and paste the function bodies of your original code into `// do something` and `// do something else`. All the logic is already there in your code, so this should be the least task.

Comment: Ha ha ok. Oh, do you know how to make work on a mobile device also?

Comment: Hm, it should actually work on mobile, too. Maybe google "jquery touch" or "html5 form mobile" or some similar terms. There are multiple libraries to create good touch optimized forms, e.g. having big enough margins so you don't click on the wrong button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't select options like you have. You're meant to give your `select` menu a reference (ID/class/name) and select that instead.

```
<select id="mySelectMenu">
    <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
    <option value="HeadAdmin">Head Admin</option>
    <option value="HeadMod">Head Modetator</option>
    <option value="HeadBuilder">Head Builder</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="Moderator">Moderator</option>
    <option value="Builder">Builder</option>
</select>
```

If you just want to detect a click on the select:

```
$('#mySelectMenu').click(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    console.log("The current selected option is "+ currentValue +".");
});
```

or maybe you want to get value of the `select` after a change was detected:

```
$('#mySelectMenu').on('change', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedValue === "Dev") {
        $("#DevTest").show();
        $("#HAtest, #HMtest, #HBtest, #adminTest, #modtest, #buildertest").hide();
    } else if (selectedValue === "HeadAdmin") {
        $("#HAtest").show();
        $("#DevTest, #HMtest, #HBtest, #adminTest, #modtest, #buildertest").hide();
    }
});
```